# How do I disable Cobertura in a child project when it is enabled by a Maven parent pom?

Tags: maven, cobertura

I have many projects which inherit from a parent pom. I enable Cobertura coverage reports in the parent via a Maven profile that is activated in our Jenkins CI builds. However, I want to disable Cobertura for **one** child project (while getting everything else from the parent pom). What is the best way to achieve this?

My first thought is to use :

```
                    <configuration>
                        <instrumentation>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>**/*.class</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </instrumentation>
```

but I'd rather just skip the entire step and not generate an "empty"  Coverage report.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the 'skip' configuration item as documented [cobertura-maven-plugin](http://mojohaus.org/cobertura-maven-plugin/instrument-mojo.html).

Comment: thanks @bmargulies.  I added <skip>true</skip> to the child pom and running help:effective-pom verifies it, but Cobertura still instrumented all the classes. I see that skip was added in 2.5 - I have been using 2.4. So, this answer sounds like a winner.

Comment: I confess that I'm probably the person who added skip to 2.5.

Comment: I found that I had to add a maven-antrun-plugin target to  <mkdir dir="${project.build.directory}/cobertura" /> because our Jenkins CI is configured (generically) to publish artifacts from " target/surefire-reports/**/*,target/cobertura/**/*,target/lib/**/*,target/*.jar,target/*.txt " and this was causing the Jenkins build to fail with <skip>true</skip>. This way, I can just change true to false and everything will work and artifacts get published.

Comment: Within our Jenkins CI env, which expects to publish Cobertura projects for all projects, I also had to create a stub site/covertura/coverage.xml file (I did this in an antrun target)  so that the Jenkins build would succeed. (I know I could disable 'Publish Cobertura Coverage Report' in the Jenkins project config, but we prefer to have uniform project configurations, i.e. no exceptions: we generate the Jenkins config from a simple template)